# Rselenium and object with wbr

Tags: html, r, parsing, rselenium

I am trying to use RSelenium to navigate with Firefox. I need to change an option button in `about:config` page for parameter **browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk**. With RSelenium I am able to find the element I need to modify, but then I cannot find a way to update the value. 
This is my HTML string to find

```
<tr class=""><th scope="row">browser.<wbr>helperApps.<wbr>neverAsk.<wbr>saveToDisk</th><td class="cell-value"><form id="form-edit"><input type="text"></form></td><td class="cell-edit"><button data-l10n-id="about-config-pref-save-button" class="primary button-save" title="Salva" form="form-edit"></button></td><td class="cell-reset"></td></tr>
```

I am using

```
 go4 = rsc$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "//th[substring-after(normalize-space(string(.)),': ')=browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk']")
```

but the error I get is

````
Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.```

How can I find the element and change the default value? 
Thank you
````